# WPF user control not changing

Tags: wpf, xaml, c#-4.0, inheritance, user-controls

I have a base class with the following:

```
public class BodyBase : UserControl
{

}
```

I then have two WPF user controls (WelcomeBody and SettingsBody) that inherit that base like:

```
public partial class WelcomeBody : BodyBase
{
    public WelcomeBody()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

I have also changed each XAML file to reflect this BaseBody and have no problem there. The designer is fine, and I can edit each control with no problem.

I placed BodyBase on my WPF form like so:

```
 <my:BodyBase x:Name="ApplicationBody" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" Background="#FFAA1111" Panel.ZIndex="-99" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Row="1" />
```

I then have on button clicked:

```
private void WelcomeClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("test");
    ApplicationBody = new WelcomeBody();
}
```

Now at run time if I click the button, I get the message box, and then once I click ok on the message box nothing happens. I debugged and there are no exceptions thrown, nothings is wrong other than the fact it does not work.

What am I doing wrong? What do I need to do do get that user control to switch.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to do

```
ApplicationBody.Content = new WelcomeBody();
```

Answer (score 1):

ApplicationBody is a code generated reference to the "bodybase" control that is initialised only once in the "foo.g.cs" partial class.  The parent container that holds the control e.g. a Grid has a different reference to the your "bodybase" control.  When you replace the "ApplicationBody" reference the Grid is still using its other reference and is pointing at the original "bodybase" control.  This is why you do not see a change.  You can see this for yourself by looking at the child elements of the parent control after you change "ApplicationBody".

The proper way to do this in WPF is to use a ContentPresenter

Answer (score 0):

You all ready have an existing control by that name assigned to your container object. Try removing the Control from your Container and adding the new one to the Container. I usally do not assign the Usercontrol in my Xaml, I add a container for the Controls and swap my items in/out of the Container.

Assuming your container is a grid named myGrid:

```
private void WelcomeClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("test");
    Thickness margin = ApplicationBody.Margin; //Preserve Usercontrol Location Unless it fills Container
    myGrid.Children.Remove(ApplicationBody);
    ApplicationBody = new WelcomeBody();
    ApplicationBody.Margin = margin;
    myGrid.Children.Add(ApplicationBody);
}
```